# jQuery goMap plugin polylines disappear if coords are more than 24

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-plugins

I have a project for S-Bahn Public Transport Network in Dusseldorf. I want to show all lines with their stations.

When I add more than 24 coords the polylines disappear. I try to remove coords in the begining, in middle and at the end - everytime it is work when the coords are bellow 24.

Here is my output code for markers and polylines.

Point using same latlng and shows on map always.

here is my output page [see the generated code](http://duesseldorf24.eu/test.php)

Is there any limitation for polylines?

When I finish this code a guess that I'll have more than 300 coord points.

Comment: I try with `$.goMap.ready(function() {` to create polylines but still no result

Comment: The best solution for me is to use KML file import